# Get cURL response in bash

Tags: bash, curl

I have a simple bash script that uploads files to an FTP. I was wondering how to get a response from curl that I can record (error or success)?

```
eval curl -T "${xmlFolder}"/"${xmlFile}" "${mediaFTP}"
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a reason you use `eval` here? It looks like it'll just cause misparsing of special characters (e.g. spaces) in the file path.

Comment: Not really. If I just drop off `eval` it will work correctly?

Comment: Unless there's a specific reason `eval` needs to be there (e.g. something in one of the variables needs to go through an additional level of parsing), you should remove it.  `eval` has a well-deserved reputation as a source of bugs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the command provided, this should suffice:

```
curl -T "$xmlFolder/$xmlFile" "$mediaFTP" || 
  printf '%s\n' $?
```

Or, if you want to discard the error message:

```
curl -T "$xmlFolder/$xmlFile" "$mediaFTP" >/dev/null || 
  printf '%s\n' $?
```

Comment: Can you explain what the %s does? and ">/dev/null" in your second bit of code? Thanks!

Comment: Hi @RGilkes, `%s` is a format string which tells printf how to display its arguments (and it means character string, in this case). See `man 3 printf` for more information.
The redirect to `/dev/null` is necessary in this case in order to discard the output the _curl_ command writes to its standard output (because, in this case, we don't need it).

Answer (score 3):

The $? bash variable indicates success (val 0) / failure (val non 0) of the previous command. So you could do:

```
eval curl -T "${xmlFolder}"/"${xmlFile}" "${mediaFTP}"
err=$?
if [ $err -ne 0 ]
then
    echo "Failed with error code $err"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: I didn't do the -1 (can't vote your own question). Just voted your answer up though.